# onClick function doesn't bind in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm a newbie to reactjs and using click handler to show/hide some div's in my webpage. The onClick method of button doesn't call the required function.
Here is a snippet of the code.

```
    showPartsInfo: function(e){
        console.log(e+" here in parts ");
        this.setState({showInfo:!this.state.showInfo});
}

return <div>
                <h3>Search Parts:</h3>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type here" />
                {
                    libraries.map(function(l){
                    return([
                        <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                     <button type="button" onClick={this.showPartsInfo}>{l.name}</button>
                                     { showInfo ? <Results /> : null }
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <a className="button btn2 cur">Move</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        ]);
                    })
                }
                </div>
}
```

I'm able to log when onChange is called but can't log when onClick is called.

Comment: What's the `show` variable in your console.log? Maybe it's undefined and it's throwing an error before setState.

Comment: @ezakto removed it and still getting error.

Comment: So... What error?

Comment: @ezakto error as in showPartsInfo doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `.map` function, you're creating a function, so you're executing all the code inside the scope of that function. So, `this.showPartsInfo` doesn't exist, because `this` is pointing to the function itself.

You have to bind that function to the component context, using `.bind()` like this:

```
                libraries.map(function(l){
                return([
                    <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-6">
                                 <button type="button" onClick={this.showPartsInfo}>{l.name}</button>
                                 { showInfo ? <Results /> : null }
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6">
                            <a className="button btn2 cur">Move</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    ]);
                }.bind(this))
```

(Notice the last line).
More on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

You can also pass the scope as a second argument, so instead of using bind, you do this:

```
libraries.map(function(l){...}, this);
```

Comment: Or if using ES6, use an arrow function since it doesn't create a new scope

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an arrow function like this:

```
libraries.map((l) => {
            return([
            ...
```

With arrow functions the value of `this` inside of the function is determined by where the arrow function is defined.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description